# Typescript - map results of Promise.allSettled back to object and retain types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to take an object of promises, and create a function that resolves them at the same time, where the result of each one is independent of the others (basically Promise.allSettled). It should then return the results in the same shape that they were originally in (the object of keys and the values are the resolved promises).

I've got it working logic wise, but I'm struggling to get the types working. After it runs through Promise.allSettled it loses the types returned by those functions, and I'm also struggling to build the object that gets returned from loadData with the types. Any tips would be appreciated..

```js
interface DataToFetch {
    [propKey: string]: ()=> Promise<any> // Assuming 'any' is incorrect, just put it as this temporarily to make more of the TS compile
}

const getFoo = async (foo: string): Promise<string[]> => {
    return ["a","b","c"]
}

const getBar = async (): Promise<number[]> => {
    return [1,2,3]
}

const loadData = async <T extends DataToFetch>(dataToFetch: T) => {
    const loadedData = await Promise.allSettled(Object.values(dataToFetch)); // This currently loses the types returned by the functions in dataToFetch
    const returnObj = {}; // Not sure how to set the type on this object so that it matches the keys passed in (it's basically the same as T but with resolved promise values.. maybe it could be done with 'Awaited', or fix the types returned by Promise.allSettled and somehow use those)

    Object.keys(dataToFetch).forEach((key,i) => {
        returnObj[key] = loadedData[i];
    });
   return returnObj; 
}

const loader = async () => {
    const data = await loadData({
        foo: getFoo('abc'),
        bar: getBar()
    });

    /** Type for 'data' should look like this:
    {
        foo: string[],
        bar: number[]
    }
    */
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the following:

```js
type PlainObj = Record<string, unknown>;
export type PromisesMap<T extends PlainObj> = {
  [P in keyof T]: Promise<T[P]> | T[P];
};

const loadData = async <T extends PlainObj>(
  promisesMap: PromisesMap<T>
): Promise<T> => {
  const resolved = await Promise.allSettled(Object.values(promisesMap));
  const toReturn: {[key: string]: unknown} = {};
  Object.keys(promisesMap).forEach((key, index)=> {
    toReturn[key] = resolved[index];
  });
  return toReturn as T;
}

const getFoo = async (foo: string): Promise<string[]> => {
    return ["a","b","c"]
}

const getBar = async (): Promise<number[]> => {
    return [1,2,3]
}

const loader = async () => {
    const data = await loadData({
        foo: getFoo('abc'),
        bar: getBar()
    });
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way here is to avoid giving the intermediate object any type and just let the TS compiler infer it. You can do that by annotating the return type - just map the `DataToFetch` interface using the built-in `Awaited` utility type.

```js
type FetchMap = {
    [key: string]: Promise<any>
}

type Fetched<T extends FetchMap>={
    [key in keyof T]: Awaited<T[key]>
}

const loadData = async <T extends FetchMap>(fetchers: T): Promise<Fetched<T>> => {
    return Object.fromEntries(await Promise.all(
        Object.entries(fetchers).map(([key, promise]) => promise.then(r => [key, r]))
    ))
}
```

Here is a working [example in a TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&jsx=0#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-KesH9INjxAj0vIICojlQIGIAHJsIZgPmmHoPfVDK5s0gXDRQx7LEwANw2cmqdQwGPg1s5ZNhUPW23EX0gP5WgHMWRAA). It uses `Object.entries` to deconstruct the object and `Object.fromEntries` to create a new one after awaiting the result which also preserves the property types.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point. Unfortunately it's not quite working correctly, it's still returning the promises around the values..  const data: Fetched<{
    foo: Promise<string[]>;
    bar: Promise<number[]>;
}>

Comment: It also throws a different TS error when you switch to using PRomise.allSettled

Comment: @richwol the type seems to be correct, for some reason, the compiler doesn't show you the unwrapped type in the hint but it's correct under the hood, you can verify it like this:
`
const result = await loadData({a: Promise.resolve(42)});
type TResult = typeof result;
const result2: TResult = {a: 42};
`

Comment: Fair, but not ideal if it doesn't show in the IDE. Thanks for your ideas though!

Comment: using Promise.allSettled is a little bit more tricky since it returns a different type, you'll need to transform PromiseSettledResult<T> -> T _somehow_
`
const mapResult = <T>(result: PromiseSettledResult<T>): T => {
    switch (result.status) {
        case "fulfilled": return result.value
        case "rejected": throw ""
    }
}
const loadData = async <T extends FetchMap>(fetchers: T): Promise<Fetched<T>> => { return Object.fromEntries((await Promise.allSettled(
        Object.entries(fetchers).map(([key, promise]) => promise.then(r => [key, r]))
    )).map(mapResult)) }
`